# Applying Mod on list of list with outcomes +1, -1, other

Tags: list-manipulation, arithmetic

I have a list

```
lis = {{7, 8}, {17, 9}, {11, 10}, {12,10}}
```

I want to apply `Mod` to each pair with output +1,-1 or `other`. I should get

```
lis2 = {-1, -1, 1, other}
```

I tried

```
Apply[Mod, lis, {1}]
```

but that just gives me all positive remainders.

Comment: Have `Mod` start at -1: `In[397]:= lis = {{7, 8}, {17, 9}, {11, 10}, {12, 10}}
Replace[Apply[Mod[##, -1] &, lis, {1}], 
 a_ /; Abs[a] =!= 1 :> "other", {1}]

Out[397]= {{7, 8}, {17, 9}, {11, 10}, {12, 10}}

Out[398]= {-1, -1, 1, "other"}`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-1` as the third argument of `Mod`:

```
Mod[##, -1] & @@@ lis
```

> {-1, -1, 1, 2}

and replace integers other than `-1` and `1` with `"other"`:

```
% /. Except[-1 | 1, _Integer] -> "other"
```

> {-1, -1, 1, "other"}

or combine the two steps:

```
Mod[##, -1] & @@@ lis /. Except[-1 | 1, _Integer] -> "other"
```

> {-1, -1, 1, "other"}

Comment: A little cleaner: `Mod[##, -1] /. Except[-1 | 1] -> "other" & @@@ lis`

Comment: Great! I understand. And how would you write   Mod[##, -1] & @@@ lis   in the Apply format?

Comment: @user57467, you can use `Apply[Mod[##, -1] &, lis, {1}]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
lis = {{7, 8}, {17, 9}, {11, 10}, {12, 10}};
```

To `Apply` `Mod` you would need to include the level specification

```
Apply[Mod, lis, {1}]

(* {7, 8, 1, 2} *)
```

or the abbreviated form

```
Mod @@@ lis

(* {7, 8, 1, 2} *)
```

Or to get the desired results

```
Module[{m = Mod @@ #}, 
   If[m == (#[[2]] - 1), -1, If[m == 1, 1, "other"]]] & /@ lis

(* {-1, -1, 1, "other"} *)
```

Comment: Wow! Good! Thank you!